# VBA txt box pass thru to spreadsheet causing error 1004 - application or object defined error

Tags: vba, excel

I've been working with a similar For Each statement dozens of times and have never run into this before. This code is intended to return values from a txt box on a user form to the appropriate column in Sheet1 based on pmNum. I have other workbooks with this code and have never received this error.

My declaration of MyCell MyCell=nothing during debug for a Run-Time 1004 error, Application-defined or object-defined error.

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

```
   Sub whatever ()

   Dim myCell as range
   Dim PmNum as string
   Dim erow

   erow = sheet1.cells(rows.count,2).end(xlup).offset(0,0).rows
   pmNum = matupdate.txtPM.value

   For each cell in worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:B" & erow)
         If cell.value = pmNum Then
         cell.offset(0,1).value = matupdate.txtdel.value
         ""
         ""
         End if
    Next
 End sub
```

Comment: .offset(0,0)? What's the point of that?

Comment: I've used it to determine the row where the value entered is located. It works. Is there an alternative?

Comment: It doesn't do anything. You can remove that bit.

Comment: Thanks!!! Learning everyday.

Answer (score 1):

```
erow = sheet1.cells(rows.count,2).end(xlup).offset(0,0).rows
```

should be

```
erow = sheet1.cells(rows.count,2).end(xlup).offset(0,0).Row
```

Also worth adding `Option Explicit` to catch things like this, as well as declaring all your variables with the most appropriate type.

Comment: Thanks! Did you see anything else that could be causing the error? Appreciate your time

Comment: Well, did that fix it?  Looks like you didn't copy/paste that code, so I didn't spend much time on the rest of it: adding the option explicit should catch most of any other issues.